# Image upload issue in php

Tags: php, joomla, image-upload

I am uploading image with `#included` name but image not display.

Example, if I created a filename `5677PlayadelRey,#4_LR.jpg`  Joomla's filesystem can not load it, But if I name `5677PlayadelRey,Unit4_LR. jpg` it worked fine.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: What do you mean "Joomla's filesystem can not load it"? What is Joomla trying to do with the image, that requires loading the image?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `#` character designates a hash/ID on the page. It is an illegal character for use within the url.

Commas `,` are also something that shouldn't be within the url

Comment: if i can use #. Can i use image name with # or Not? my client want to use image name with #

Answer (score 1):

You can use `urlencode` to make sure your filename is safe for URLs.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

You can use this only when you need to use the filename in a URL. You can keep your filenames whatever you want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

`#` is not passed  in URL so use anything Replace with `#`

Answer (score 0):

try this with

```
<?php
    // define a constant for the maximum upload size
    define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 1024 * 50);

    if (array_key_exists('upload', $_POST)) {
      // define constant for upload folder
      define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/path/to/images/');
      // replace any spaces in original filename with underscores
      $file = str_replace('#', '_', $_FILES['image']['name']);
      // create an array of permitted MIME types
      $permitted = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg',
    'image/png');

      // upload if file is OK
      if (in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], $permitted)
          && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0 
          && $_FILES['image']['size'] <= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        switch($_FILES['image']['error']) {
          case 0:
            // check if a file of the same name has been uploaded
            if (!file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $file)) {
              // move the file to the upload folder and rename it
              $success =
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR .
    $file);
            } else {
              $result = 'A file of the same name already exists.';
            }
            if ($success) {
              $result = "$file uploaded successfully.";
            } else {
              $result = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
            }
            break;
          case 3:
          case 6:
          case 7:
          case 8:
            $result = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
            break;
          case 4:
            $result = "You didn't select a file to be uploaded.";
        }
      } else {
        $result = "$file is either too big or not an image.";
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Joomla, require all filenames be alphanumeric + underscore.  Many plugins you install will likely be based on this assumption.  Things will likely break otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In your method that is processing the image:

```
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

then, use

```
$your_photo_name = JFile::makeSafe($input->get('your_photo_name');
```

This will make the filename to be safe to be used by the Joomla! system